# Where is Lucene's BaseTokenStreamFactoryTestCase in the Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, solr, lucene

I am currently writing a Lucene Tokenizer and I want to test my class. For the test, I got inspiration from the Lucene test class [TestStandardFactories](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/TestStandardFactories.java) which is a child class of the testing class [BaseTokenStreamTestCase](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/BaseTokenStreamTestCase.java). Accordingly my test class is also a child class of *BaseTokenStreamTestCase*.

I apply Maven and hence my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.institute.taggedtexttokenizer</groupId>
  <artifactId>tagged-text-tokenizer</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>

  <properties>
        <lucene-version>7.2.0</lucene-version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-test-framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
    <version>${lucene-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>${lucene-version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
    <version>${lucene-version}</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I expected the *BaseTokenStreamTestCase* to be in the lucene-test-framework and hence my test to run properly. However, the compiler complains that it cannot find the class *BaseTokenStreamTestCase*. A quick look in the lucene-test-framework assured me that this class is not contained in there.

Which Maven dependency do I need to include to have access to this class?

Answer (score 0):

I double checked and `lucene-test-framework` artifact contains needed class: `org.apache.lucene.analysis.BaseTokenStreamTestCase`.

One of the possible reasons, why compiler complaints about this class is, because you are using `<scope>test</scope>`, which means, that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the **test** compilation and execution phases.

For example, you may put this test into `src/main/java` place, so it's test dependency couldn't pick it up.